# ¿Asp.net Core + Angular necesitan licencia?

Tags: angular, vue.js, asp.net-core-mvc

Necesito comprar una **licencia** para poner en producción un proyecto Asp.net Core MVC ya sea con angular, Vue o cualquier otro para el frontend?

El proyecto estará en la infraestructura de la empresa, el tema es que no quiero que luego en una auditoria digan que es necesario tener licencia.

Gracias.

Comment: Lecturas obligatorias: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/LICENSE.txt + https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/LICENSE + https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/LICENSE TL;DR? Una licencia MIT te permite uso comercial.

Comment: Comprendo. Muchas gracias, no se me había ocurrido ver eso, Puedes ponerlo como respuesta para darle fin a la pregunta, gracias @fredyfx

Comment: Un gusto colaborar, sí, claro, ahora la publico, no lo hice antes porque la pregunta como tal está en una zona donde no sé si tiene chance de ser cerrada o no, aparte la respuesta tampoco está detallada por ser enlaces y una oración.

Comment: por cierto, para marcar una respuesta como aceptada, se da click en el check del costado de la respuesta, esto solo lo puede hacer la persona que pregunta. Saludos :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Asp.net Core**

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/LICENSE.txt

**Angular**

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/LICENSE

**VueJS**

https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/LICENSE

Las licencias de estos 3 frameworks son MIT y este tipo de licencia permite el uso comercial.